# Apps Script coming up as 'undefined' in email

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to setup an Apps Script to send an email automatically when a word appears in a cell using information in that row. I have everything written the same way, but for some reason, it comes up as 'undefined' for only one of the lines. Here is the code:

```
function sendMailEdit(e){
    if (e.range.columnStart != 22 || e.value != "DONE") return;

    const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,2,2,4).getValues();

    let email = rData[0][0];

    let name = rData[0][2];

    let resolution = rData[0][19];

    let msg = "Hello - Your office referral for " + name + " has been addressed in the following way: " + resolution + ". If you have any questions, please let me know!"
    
    MailApp.sendEmail(email, "Office Referral: Counseling", msg)
}
```

It pulls the data correctly and emails it exactly the way I want it to for the " + name +" portion, but NOT the " + resolution + " portion. I don't understand!

I have tried rewriting the entire code several times, setting the number from '19' to several other numbers above and below 19, and I have tried multiple different naming conventions instead of 'resolution'

Comment: Perhaps you are attempting to run the onEdit function from the script editor.  You can do that as long as you provide the event object.  Please provide and exact copy of the error.

Comment: Are you sure that you get all your values of interest with getRange(e.range.rowStart,2,2,4)? It seems that the length of the array rData[0] is only 5.